# How to store data from option inputs in React useState

Tags: reactjs, object, input, use-state

Im triying to fill the following object:

```
const [customer, setCustomer] = useState({
    identification: "",
    id_type: {
        code: "",
        name: ""
    },
    name: "",
    surname: ""
})
```

I don´t really have any problem with identification, name or surname. The problem comes with id_type and hes values.
To update all the values im using the following code:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setCustomer((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
}
```

this code works perfect for this simple data type:

```
<FormGroup>
<Label for="identification">User Id</Label>
     <Input
        id="identification"
        name="identification"
        placeholder="Type the user id"
        type="text"
        value={customer.identification}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
      />
</FormGroup>
```

However for id_type im having a list of options:

```
<FormGroup>
<Label for="customer.id_type.name">Id type for customer</Label>
    <Input onChange={handleChange} id="customer.id_type.name" name="customer.id_type.name" type="select">
       <option value="13" name="customer.id_type.code" onChange={handleChange}>Citizenship card</option>
       <option value="31" name="customer.id_type.code" onChange={handleChange}>NIT</option>
    </Input>
</FormGroup>
```

All I want its that if the user selects the option  "Citizenship card" then the object fills as it follows:

```
{
identification: "xxx-xxxx-xxxxx",
  id_type: {
    code: "13",
    name: "Citizenship card"
  },
  name: "xxxxxx",
  surname: "xxxxxxx"
}
```

And if he pick "NIT" it should be filled with:

```
{
  identification: "xxx-xxxx-xxxxx",
  id_type: {
    code: "31",
    name: "NIT"
  },
  name: "xxxxxx",
  surname: "xxxxxxx"
}
```

Currently all i can get its something like this: [customer object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZbpD.png)
and im not been able to get id_type and hes values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `e.target.name` use `e.target.getAttribute('name')`.

So it will look something like this:

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setCustomer((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [e.target.getAttribute('name')]: e.target.value
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, It makes a little difference, now I can see the ID of the option, however its creating a new variable "id_type.id_type.name = 31" and not putting it inside the id_type { code: " " }